# Ok to use 0 and 1 for a varaible in a linear regression?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, linear-model

Ok this is a simple quesion that's been bugging me. The question is how to encode a linear model variable with only two possible values and avoid any trouble introduced by using zero.
Say you have a linear model:

```
outcomeVariable ~ DayOrNight
```

How should you properly encode DayOrNight? There are only two choices and they're unordered. You could say DayOrNight is categorical independent variable.

Now, is it bad to fill the variable with entries of 0 or 1 as integers? It feels like an entry of zero would mean that term will always contribute zero to the outcomeVariable, no matter the beta coefficient. So will Beta only be meaningful when DayorNight=1?
If you choose -1 vs 1, or 1 vs 2, then your fit parameters and pvalues change. That troubles me.

If you force that variable to be categorical in statsmodels or R, it's just like using 0 or 1. So maybe I'm paranoid and people have thought about this before and it's ok.

Comment: There are other ways to encode: -1/1, for example. If there are more than two categories, the number of coding schemes proliferate. If you have multiple categorical variables on the right hand side of the model, and you are including interaction terms with them, you will likely want to stick to effect coding to avoid inducing artificial heteroscedasticity.

Comment: Translation: effect coding = -1/1,  dummy coding = 0/1. http://methodology.psu.edu/node/266

Comment: That's effect coding for a single binary variable. Effect coding is a bit more complicated for more than two categories. See Glantz, S. A. and Slinker, B. (2000). *Primer of Applied Regression and Analysis of Variance*, chapter 8: Two-Way Analysis of Variance, pages 339–417. McGraw-Hill Medical, New York, NY, 2nd edition for a discussion of the issues arising when interacting with categorical predictors.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is it okay to code it as 0/1, it's [common to do so](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29).

> It feels like an entry of zero would mean that term will always contribute zero to the outcomeVariable, no matter the beta coefficient.

Correct. This is not a problem. The intercept has the mean for the 0 category, and the coefficient for the 0/1 variable has the difference in means between the two categories.

> So will Beta only be meaningful when DayorNight=1? If you choose -1 vs 1, or 1 vs 2, then your fit parameters and pvalues change. That troubles me.

The p-value for this variable shouldn't change from such recoding. The estimated coefficient will change, of course, and the coefficient (and p-value) for the intercept will change, because such recoding changes the meaning of the intercept.

> If you force that variable to be categorical in statsmodels or R, it's just like using 0 or 1.

It doesn't matter whether it's numeric or a factor. In R, if you use a two level factor (Say with levels `Day` and `Night`), it simply creates a 0/1 variable itself. You can see this by calling `model.matrix` on the RHS of your model formula.

Comment: I'm seeing the pvalue for one term change in an interaction model.

Comment: outcomeVariable=DayNight+eastWest+DayNight*eastWest. DayNight and DayNight*eastWest are staying consistent, but eastWest changes when I use -1/1 or 1/2 or 0.25/0.75.

Comment: You didn't mention *anything* about interaction in your question. The only model you mention in your question is: `outcomeVariable ~ DayOrNight`. My answer relates to that model, not to the infinity of models you didn't mention. (I'm not a mind-reader!)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. In a simple interaction model, does it make sense that one of the interacting terms might be changing while the other term and the interaction term are fixed relative to recoding?

Comment: Interaction terms should change yes.